# Single url for a product which is in different category in magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, url, products, product-urls

I have a product black-jacket under the category men->tops 
when i click on men the url is like http://magento2/men/black-jacket.html 
and if i click on tops under the men then the url is http://magento2/men/tops/black-jackets.html 
i want the url like http://magento2/tops/black-jacket.html on the click of both the menu in magento 2.
please suggest me, i tried to do it with url-rewrites.

Answer (score 1):

Please do try with this option :  setting up the search engine optimization settings by configuration / catalog / catalog[image]

As shown in the picture, **Use Categories Path for Product URLs** to `No`

Comment: Yes, i know this. it will remove all categories from the url but i want to show the subcategory in the url